# Is System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Stop() synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: .net, service, servicecontroller

... or `.Start()` for that matter?

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.stop(v=vs.110).aspx) says nothing about it.  [There are no relevant google results](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&ei=RQpWWsW0FcnnzgLR_oToDQ&q=Is%20System.ServiceProcess.servicecontroller.stop%20synchronous%20or%20asynchronous%3F&oq=Is%20System.ServiceProcess.servicecontroller.stop%20synchronous%20or%20asynchronous%3F&gs_l=psy-ab.3...133381.164222.0.166487.26.24.0.0.0.0.392.2423.0j9j3j1.13.0....0...1.1j2.64.psy-ab..16.2.550...0j35i39k1.0.splZh_AnQq0) that touch on this question.  [Reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceProcess/System/ServiceProcess/ServiceController.cs,b6683ca5de65cbe1) doesn't include the method body for some reason.

In testing it, it's tough to tell because the services that I'm willing to stop all do so very quickly.

**EDIT:** I'm not asking if it's implementing one of the asynchronous patterns -- it's obviously not; I'm just wondering if it the method sends a request to stop the service but doesn't wait to hear back, much like [`Process.CloseMainWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: But you _can_ see that the methods _do not_ end with `Async`, and that they are voids in Reference Source. Those two indications should be enough, right?

Comment: Not all asynchronous methods end in async.  I'm not asking if this method implements async-await; it obviously doesn't.

Comment: @RickvandenBosch -- see my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Sounds plausible that `ServiceController.Stop()` _triggers_ the stop of a service, but doesn't _wait_ for it. Probably commented too fast... :/

Answer (score 3):

Okay I was finally able to answer my own question, and the answer is: the call to `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Stop()` is *asynchronous*, i.e. control returns immediately while the service itself may take quite a bit longer to actually stop.

I confirmed this by building my own service which, when stopped, waits 20 seconds before completing.  The call to `Stop()`, however, returns right away.